Conversion of RE into finite automata
Is this conversion of the regular expression  L(((011 + 11)∗(00)∗)∗) into the transition diagram of a finite automata good? Please guide me into what could be wrong, I did it two times differently.


We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See here and here. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Perhaps I should give you a little more context about the purpose of this site.  This site is a place where people can collaborate to build a high-quality archive of knowledge that will be helpful to others, in the form of questions and answers.  This means that questions should generally be about some general topic that will be useful to others, and formulated in a way that others who have the same question can find this via websearch.

It also means that we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, to make sure the question will be valuable to others and will add to the archive of knowledge.  There's probably not much point in us repeating material that's already contained in standard textbooks, or solving exercises that test ability to apply those standard concepts, so if your question is asking how to do something already found in textbooks, it might not be a good fit here.

There can be multiple correct answers.  Any good textbook will provide an algorithm for converting a regexp to a finite automaton.  Follow that algorithm, one step at a time, and the result will be correct (if you followed the recipe correctly).
If you want to check whether your result is correct, a standard approach is to convert both the regexp and automaton to DFAs, then check whether they accept the same language by computing the symmetric difference (using the product construction).  Or, you could convert both to regular expressions and test whether the two regular expressions are equivalent; both steps can be done mechanically using known algorithms.
Since this is a purely mechanical construction, I leave it to you to do the tedious work, as doing another worked example won't have any more value to others in the future than checking whether $230923 \times 9572 = 2210384956$.
I suggest reviewing a good textbook on automata theory / formal languages, and these resources: What is the correct way to draw NFA of RE (a|b|c)?, How to create DFA from regular expression without using NFA?, "Best" automaton for a regular language, Steps to convert regular expressions directly to regular grammars and vice versa, Proving Equivalence of Two Regular Expressions, Does Thompson's algorithm produce optimal NFAs?, How to prove a language is regular?, Does every regular expression describe only 1 language?, Check whether a regular expression is correct, Algorithm to determine whether two regexes are equivalent, Proving Equivalence of Two Regular Expressions, Equivalence of regular expressions.

It’s also useful to first try to think about what the language of the RE is, which can lead to simplifications. E.g., here the RE can be simplified to $(0^11)^(00)^*$, which easily translates to a 3-state automaton.
